# How to use an R if else statement in a loop for each row

Tags: r, for-loop

I am looking to apply an if else statement for each row in a dataset for a specific column in R. I want to have it loop through every row and check the value in a certain column to be greater or less than 150, and then assign a 1 or a 0 in a new column based on this. Below is the code that I am currently working with, when run however, only 0's are returned.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(RawData)){
 
  RawData[i, 5] <-   
    if(RawData$users <= 150) {
      1
    } else {
      0
    }
  
}

head(RawData)
```

Any advice would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We don't need any loop or `ifelse`, just create a logical expression (which is vectorized) and coerce to integer with either `+` or `as.integer` (`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0)

```
+(RawData$users <= 150)
```

Comment: I am just thinking theoretically how I might do this. I will be using the implementation for another problem, but need to know how to assign a conditional value for each row depending on the value.

Comment: @arhomberg do you want a `if/else` or `ifelse`

Comment: Eventually it will have multiple clauses so it will have an if then an else if, else if etc. It will essentially a sign a value based on if the number is within a certain range. like 0-50, 51-100, etc.

Comment: @arhomberg that you can do with `cut` i.e. `with(RawData, cut(users, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 50, 100, 150, Inf)))`